# Count records below the 30% percentile

Tags: r, count, quantile

I have a table like

```
mtcars
```

I need to count how many models are velow the 30% percentile.  I found that perecentile. but I do not found how to count them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ quantile(.x, 0.30 ) ))
```

> ```
> mpg cyl   disp    hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> 1 15.98   4 142.06 106.2 3.15 2.773 17.02  0  0    3    2
> ```

mtcars %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ quantile(.x, 0.30 ) ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert to a logical vector (`.x < quantile(.x, 0.30)`) and get the count with `sum` - as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.x < quantile(.x, 0.30 ) )))
```

-output

```
   mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
1  10   0   10 10    9 10    9  0  0    0    7
```

Comment: Exactly what I asked for.
Thank you very much, @akrun !

Answer (score 1):

In base R you may do

```
num <- sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)
sapply(mtcars[num], \(x) sum(x < quantile(x, .3)))
# mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
#  10    0   10   10    9   10    9    0    0    0    7
```

or

```
colSums(mtcars[num] < lapply(mtcars[num], quantile, .3))
# mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
#  10    0   10   10    9   10    9    0    0    0    7
```

or (using `matrixStats::colQuantiles`)

```
colSums(mtcars[num] < as.list(matrixStats::colQuantiles(as.matrix(mtcars[num]), probs=.3)))
# mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
#  10    0   10   10    9   10    9    0    0    0    7
```

Comment: Really nice approach!
I thought it was possible "only" with dplyr.
Do not know how it could be used for analyzing tibbles. But that is another problem.